# How to number two alphabetical characters correctly?

Tags: algorithm, hash

I am trying to create a **hash function** in C that outputs an integer between 0 and 675 based on a word inputted to it... the reason that the range is so vast is because instead of categorizing words by their first letter I decided to categorize them by their first two since I have a huge amount of words to store, so the question finally is...

**how to return a number that is from 0 to 675 in such a way that for example "aa" would be 0 and "ab" would be one and "ac" would be 2 and "bb" would be 27 and so on...?**

***TL;DR* just read the last sentence.**

**Note:** For those who think that I should just loop through a set of all the possible combinations, I've thought of that... I just think that there would be a better and maybe faster way instead of looping through a set of 676 elements for each and every word.

Comment: Why would `bb` be 26 and not 27? Since `az` is 25 and now `ba` should be 26 if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Yonlif oh yeah my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that looping over the letters in your word would be enough. Loop from last to first and for each letter add it to the hash times 26 power the length of your string, remember all of this should be % 675.

So a code in C that does that can look like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char word[100];
    scanf("%s", word);
    int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        hash += ((word[strlen(word) - i - 1] - 'a') * (int) pow(26, i)) % 675;
        hash %= 675;
    }
    printf("hash(%s) = %d\n", word, hash);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

> bb

Output:

> hash(bb) = 27

Feel free to ask if something is unclear, hope it is indeed answering your question.

Comment: The math of it really confuses me but I tested it and it works... just be sure to only input it the first two letters of your word only. cause if you input more the thing will break, and create a separate branch for "zz" since the modulo(675) of 675 is = 0